# How to make dropdown menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building navbar I stacked with the dropdown menu. Here is my codes:

I also want to open the list when I hover over the menu.

Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        @*Logo*@
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Halo Dayi</a>
        </div>

        @*Menu İtems*@
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                @*DropDown Menu*@
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>



    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css to activate while hovering over the dropdown menu

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns:

> Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown, or another element that declares position: relative;

So, your markup is OK, just check that the `<li class="dropdown">` does have relative position or else wrap it in a div.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I could not understand what I am supposed to do. Can  you show the code block please?